# Just some Validation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Anyone know how to validate this? I'm just experimenting on how to make my code more concise.

```
def hard():
print ("Hard mode code goes here.\n")

def medium():
print ("medium mode code goes here\n")

def easy():
print ("easy mode code goes here\n")

def lazy():
print ("i don't want to play\n")

choose_mode = {0 : hard,
       1 : medium,
       4 : lazy,
       9 : easy,}

user_input=int(input("which mode do you want to choose : \n press 0 for hard \n press 1 for medium \n press 4 for lazy \n press 9 for easy "))
choose_mode[user_input]()
```

Thanks for any replies in advance

Comment: How to validate what exactly?

Comment: Also, format your code. This indentation is not valid.

Comment: Why is this tagged with python2.7 *and* python3.x...? Which is it? Are you running both versions?

Comment: I'm assuming Python 3 because of `print()` statements.

Comment: @alex Those are valid in python2 as well.

Comment: @glibdud Fair enough, I rolled back my edit.

Comment: @alex You're probably right, though; see also the `input()` statement. Unfortunately, that also technically works in python2 in this situation. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: @glibdud yes I am running both but I think I have the answer now so its fine. thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
choice = None
while choice is None:
    user_input = int(input("which mode do you want to choose : \n press 0 for hard \n press 1 for medium \n press 4 for lazy \n press 9 for easy "))
    choice = choose_mode.get(user_input)
```

The `get` method on dictionaries will return `None` if the key does not exist. You can check for this in a loop and prompt the user again if they give an invalid answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if user_input in (0,1,4,9): 
    pass
else:
    Restart
```

Is this something you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You've got more issues than just validation.

First, the body of your functions need to be indented - remember that Python is indentation-sensitive:

```
def hard():
    print ("Hard mode code goes here.\n")

def medium():
    print ("medium mode code goes here\n")

def easy():
    print ("easy mode code goes here\n")

def lazy():
    print ("i don't want to play\n")
```

`choose_mode` doesn't look correct. It's a dictionary where the first entry's key is `0` (`0` is an integer, so no problem), but what is `hard`?  `hard()` is a reference to a function, but `hard` isn't so clear.

I'm assuming you want to let the user enter *numbers* for ease-of-access, but you don't want to use semantically-meaningless numbers throughout your application logic (which is good practice!).  If that's the case, `choose_mode` can be repurposed to map arbitrary numbers to semantically-meaningful strings:

```
choose_mode = {
    0: "hard",
    1: "medium",
    4: "lazy",
    9: "easy"
}

user_input = int(input("which mode do you want to choose : \n press 0 for hard \n press 1 for medium \n press 4 for lazy \n press 9 for easy "))
```

Now you can validate the user input using `if/else` conditions.  Dictionary values are accessed via a dictionary's `.get()` method:

```
if choose_mode.get(user_input) == "hard":
    hard()
elif choose_mode.get(user_input) == "medium":
    medium()
elif choose_mode.get(user_input) == "easy":
    easy()
elif choose_mode.get(user_input) == "lazy":
    lazy()
else:
    # the user's input was neither 0, nor 1, nor 4, nor 9
    print "invalid"
```

Putting it all together:

```
def hard():
    print ("Hard mode code goes here.\n")

def medium():
    print ("medium mode code goes here\n")

def easy():
    print ("easy mode code goes here\n")

def lazy():
    print ("i don't want to play\n")

choose_mode = {
    0: "hard",
    1: "medium",
    4: "lazy",
    9: "easy"
}

user_input = int(input("which mode do you want to choose : \n press 0 for hard \n press 1 for medium \n press 4 for lazy \n press 9 for easy "))

if choose_mode.get(user_input) == "hard":
    hard()
elif choose_mode.get(user_input) == "medium":
    medium()
elif choose_mode.get(user_input) == "easy":
    easy()
elif choose_mode.get(user_input) == "lazy":
    lazy()
else:
    print("invalid")
```